# Get secret from hashicorp vault using java application with service token

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, hashicorp-vault

Maybe some could help me understand where I missed something.

I use such [example](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-config-vault) to set-up cloud-config service, with another spring application which is used vault to get some secrets.

If I using `root` token everything is working correctly.

But once I create `service` token with policy

```
path "secret/data/test*" {
  capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}

path "secret/test*" {
  capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
```

I can validate it with

```
$ vault token capabilities secret/test
create, delete, list, read, update
```

and with curl

```
$ curl \
--header "X-Vault-Token: $VAULT_TOKEN" \
http://<dns-name>:8200/v1/secret/data/test | jq .
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   302  100   302    0     0   2796      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2796
{
  "request_id": "44b5fdcf-a13c-8e12-83f3-a5064f25257d",
  "lease_id": "",
  "renewable": false,
  "lease_duration": 0,
  "data": {
    "data": {
      "test-key": "test-value"
    },
    "metadata": {
      "created_time": "2020-04-09T21:11:28.899688798Z",
      "deletion_time": "",
      "destroyed": false,
      "version": 1
    }
  },
  "wrap_info": null,
  "warnings": null,
  "auth": null
}
```

but once I start using this token with the application it returns

```
2020-04-10 13:38:43.186 DEBUG 43843 --- [nio-8888-exec-1] org.apache.http.wire: http-outgoing-0 >> “GET /v1/secret/data/test HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]”
http-outgoing-0 >> “X-Vault-Token: <TOKEN>[\r][\n]”
Response 403 FORBIDDEN
```

Comment: i dont know much about spring and this might be wrong but i'd expect `“X-Vault-Token: <TOKEN>[\r][\n]”` to be `“X-Vault-Token: <TOKEN>”`

Comment: i think if you will be right, this will not work with `root` token also

Comment: you can see the thread in github https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1594

Answer (score 1):

It really sounds like the app is not attaching the credentials correctly. Try hitting a site like [httpbin](https://httpbin.org/). 
The [/anything](https://httpbin.org/#/Anything/post_anything) will return the request that it received. Its an easy way to debug those services.

You can also host that site locally if you are worried about those credentials.

Comment: Thanks, for the this point i will try it.
Hmm, I’ll try this, but very strange that in the internet I didn’t find any information about such implementation, and it is hard to debug it.

Comment: I find out one thing, that if I add empty `secret/application/<Environment>` it starts getting data from the vault with my newly created policy.